# How do you remove "onclick" from an HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to only peform the `onlick` before a button is pressed. How can I remove the `onclick` so that they don't pass anything?

```html
<!-- remove onclick -->
<div class="boardsection2" id="2_8_7" onclick="divclick('2_8_7')"></div>

<!-- button to execute the removal of onclick -->
<button class="testclass" id="testid" onclick="test()">finish setup</button>
```

I tried with

```js
document.getElementByClassName("boardsection1").removeAttribute("onclick")
```

but it did not affect anything.

Comment: use addEventListener() and removeEventListener() instead of onclick

Comment: Or, unless it's _extremely_ clear why the button is disabled, change the click handler to one that gives a message why it cannot be used. If it's never going to be used again, you could remove the button entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Assign `null` to the `onclick` property:

```
document.getElementById("boardsection1").onclick = null;
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<button class="testclass" id="testid" onclick="test()">finish setup</button>

<script>
  let button = document.getElementById("testid");
  button.removeAttribute("onclick");
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any improvement over @mtalhastar's existing answer.